# How to recreate intuitively a geometric series when you know the sum it converges against?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given $x=ax+b$, $0<a<1$ solving for $x$ you get the sum $$\frac{b}{1-a}$$ but how can one intuitively come up with the geometric series $$b+ba+ba^2+...+ba^n $$

Comment: With enough experience working with infinite geometric series, you recognize that $$\text{for}~~|a| < 1, ~~\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a^k = \frac{1}{1-a}.$$  Not really different from a pianist hearing a melody and recognizing the musical notes involved.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you are looking for?

$$\begin{align}x&=ax+b\\&=a(ax+b)+b=a^2x+ab+b\\\vdots\\&=a(a(a(\ldots)+b)+b)+b=b+ba+ba^2+ba^3+\ldots\end{align}$$